# (remote rejected) master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)

Tags: node.js, git, mongodb, express, heroku

I'm having problems pushing to Heroku. This is happening on my first "Git push Heroku Master." I'm using Node JS.

The error I am getting is as follows:

Take a look at the entire error log below. Please let me know where I am going wrong while attempting to push my project to Heoku.

```
   andrewleonardi:~/workspace/HelpMeRV/V1 (master) $ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 39, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (35/35), done.
Writing objects: 100% (39/39), 11.80 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 39 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: 
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote: 
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  4.1.1
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        
remote:        Downloading and installing node 4.1.1...
remote:        Using default npm version: 2.14.4
remote: 
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Skipping cache restore (new runtime signature)
remote: 
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json)
remote:        
remote:        > deasync@0.1.9 install /tmp/build_7c427b7600b55b6ea32823b63fa7f741/node_modules/locus/node_modules/deasync
remote:        > node ./build.js
remote:        
remote:        `linux-x64-node-4` exists; testing
remote:        Binary is fine; exiting
remote:        
remote:        > nodewebkit@0.11.6 postinstall /tmp/build_7c427b7600b55b6ea32823b63fa7f741/node_modules/nodewebkit
remote:        > node scripts/install.js
remote:        
remote:        stream.js:74
remote:        throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
remote:        ^
remote:        
remote:        Error: invalid tar file
remote:        at Extract.Parse._startEntry (/tmp/build_7c427b7600b55b6ea32823b63fa7f741/node_modules/nodewebkit/node_modules/download/node_modules/decompress/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:145:13)
remote:        at Extract.Parse._process (/tmp/build_7c427b7600b55b6ea32823b63fa7f741/node_modules/nodewebkit/node_modules/download/node_modules/decompress/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:127:12)
remote:        at BlockStream.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_7c427b7600b55b6ea32823b63fa7f741/node_modules/nodewebkit/node_modules/download/node_modules/decompress/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:47:8)
remote:        at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
remote:        at BlockStream.emit (events.js:169:7)
remote:        at BlockStream._emitChunk (/tmp/build_7c427b7600b55b6ea32823b63fa7f741/node_modules/nodewebkit/node_modules/download/node_modules/decompress/node_modules/tar/node_modules/block-stream/block-stream.js:145:10)
remote:        at BlockStream.resume (/tmp/build_7c427b7600b55b6ea32823b63fa7f741/node_modules/nodewebkit/node_modules/download/node_modules/decompress/node_modules/tar/node_modules/block-stream/block-stream.js:58:15)
remote:        at Extract.Reader.resume (/tmp/build_7c427b7600b55b6ea32823b63fa7f741/node_modules/nodewebkit/node_modules/download/node_modules/decompress/node_modules/tar/node_modules/fstream/lib/reader.js:255:34)
remote:        at DirWriter.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_7c427b7600b55b6ea32823b63fa7f741/node_modules/nodewebkit/node_modules/download/node_modules/decompress/node_modules/tar/lib/extract.js:57:8)
remote:        at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
remote:        npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-112-generic
remote:        npm ERR! argv "/tmp/build_7c427b7600b55b6ea32823b63fa7f741/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_7c427b7600b55b6ea32823b63fa7f741/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "install" "--unsafe-perm" "--userconfig" "/tmp/build_7c427b7600b55b6ea32823b63fa7f741/.npmrc"
remote:        npm ERR! node v4.1.1
remote:        npm ERR! npm  v2.14.4
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! nodewebkit@0.11.6 postinstall: `node scripts/install.js`
remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the nodewebkit@0.11.6 postinstall script 'node scripts/install.js'.
remote:        npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the nodewebkit package,
remote:        npm ERR! not with npm itself.
remote:        npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
remote:        npm ERR!     node scripts/install.js
remote:        npm ERR! You can get their info via:
remote:        npm ERR!     npm owner ls nodewebkit
remote:        npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/build_7c427b7600b55b6ea32823b63fa7f741/npm-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to frozen-escarpment-22835.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/frozen-escarpment-22835.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/frozen-escarpment-22835.git'
```

Comment: Please upload the whole build log

Comment: @Varedis Done!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [package](https://github.com/shama/nodewebkit) there are a few other open issues with the same issue you are having.

However, you may want to checkout the big **ATTENTION** label in the readme and try updating to the latest renamed version and see if you have the same issue

> ATTENTION
>
> node-webkit was renamed to nw.js as of version 0.12.0. The new and
>   official installer for nw.js is now npm install nw and the repo is
>   located at github.com/nwjs/npm-installer
>
> All future releases >= 0.12.0 will be released through nw.

Comment: This pretty much did the trick! Thank you. I installed the new node-webkit (npm install nw) and took the old one out of the package.json. I did keep the "start": "node app.js" in the package.json and everything is working. 

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/new-cv-meker.git'

find this line in your code : Two different lockfiles found: package-lock.json and yarn.lock

And Delete Your yarn.lock file and also uninstall package